# Django: list_display accepts field but not list_filter

Tags: python, django, class, admin

I have the following admin class:

```
class AppointmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('branch', 'date', 'timeslot', 'sold_to', 'unit', 'VIN')
    list_filter = ('branch', 'date', 'sold_to', 'unit', 'VIN')

    def VIN(self, obj):
        return obj.unit.vin
```

I get the following error:

```
<class 'catalog.admin.AppointmentAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[4]' refers to 'VIN', which does not refer to a Field.
```

If I remove VIN from list_filter, it executes fine.  The list_display *will* show me the field VIN.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the field in your model VIN or vin?

Comment: I have two models.  One is that is Vehicle that has both 'unit' and 'vin' (both lowercase).  The __str__ in that model returns 'unit'.  I also have an Appointment model.  In this, I tried to refer to both 'unit' & 'vin' with foreign keys but django would return the value of the 'unit' to both the 'unit' and 'vin' field.
To get the 'vin' to display in the admin model, I had to define the 'vin' but I used 'VIN' to differentiate them.

Comment: Could you please share the `model.py` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List filter doesn’t support ModelAdmin methods.

To filter on the vin based on your VIN method you would need to have unit__vin in the list_filter.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter